# Exception calling AWS Send-SQSMessage PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

## Environment

- Windows 7
- WMF / PowerShell 5.0 installed
- AWS PowerShell version 3.3.36.0

## Scenario

I'm trying to use the Amazon Web Services (AWS) PowerShell module to send a message to a queue. However, when I invoke the `Send-SQSMessage` command, I'm getting an exception thrown:

> Send-SQSMessage : The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.

I've already set up my AWS credentials in the `~/.aws/credentials` file, using the `Set-AWSCredentials` command. Here's the command I'm calling:

```
$text = (Get-ChildItem)[1] | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1
Send-SQSMessage -QueueUrl https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/redacted/myqueuename -MessageBody $text -ProfileName TrevorAWS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message can pop up when the configured region doesn't match up to the AWS resource that you're working with. To configure the region correctly, you have a couple of choices:

1. Use the `Set-DefaultAWSRegion` command to configure the default region. This prevents the need to specify the `-Region` parameter on
2. You can specify the `-Region` parameter on any AWS cmdlet, and force it to use that region for that single command invocation.
3. Use the `Initialize-AWSDefaults` command to set up your PowerShell environment.

After configuring the correct region, that correlates to your AWS SQS queue, the `Send-SQSMessage` command should execute without throwing any exceptions.